# How can I enter values into an excel cell with out erasing its formula?

Tags: excel, formula

I'm creating an excel spreadsheet that will have certain formulas. For now I'm using this formula, =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Pass",F15)),F15,"") which says if Cell F15 has the word Pass then copy that pass to THIS cell. But sometimes THIS cell will have FAIL or any other string. I want to be able to enter this string but still keep the formula there, so when cell F15 has a PASS, it will copy it to THIS cell.

Comment: [this may help](https://superuser.com/q/813639/141414)

Answer (score 0):

Put your other text or a reference to it in your formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Pass",F15)),F15,"ENTER YOUR OPTIONAL TEXT HERE OR A CELL REFERENCE")
```

Comment: but that text/cell can either be blank, fail, not applicable and many others.